# Can you split a string and keep the split char(s)?

Tags: c#, split

Is there a way to split a string but keep the split char(s), if you do this:

`"A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H".Split(new char[] { '+' });`

you get

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Is there a way to use split so it would keep the split char:

```
A
+B
+C
+D
+E
+F
+G
+H
```

or if you were to have `+` in front of `A` then

```
+A
+B
+C
+D
+E
+F
+G
+H
```

Comment: what is this use case? if you want to split but keep the split char then you surely end up with the original string? or do you mean you want to inject Environment.NewLine between each delimiter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Split` with a pattern that doesn't consume delimiter characters:

```
var pattern = @"(?=\+)";

var ans = Regex.Split(src, pattern);
```

This will create an empty entry if there is a leading `+` as there is an implied split before the `+`.

You could use LINQ to remove the empty entries if they aren't wanted:

```
var ans2 = Regex.Split(src, pattern).Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, you could use `Regex.Matches` to extract the full matching patterns:

```
var ans3 = Regex.Matches(src, @"(?:^|\+)[^+]*").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Excellent catch!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I feel like you may have commented on the wrong post? I had no idea VP Planner was written in FORTH (I used it once upon a time). Seems like a very bad language choice for that type of application...

Comment: I saw Forth in your profile, which is pretty unusual, which is why I commented. Will delete this comment when I figure you've seen it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah. Yes, I was heavily influenced by Aug 1980 issue of Byte magazine on Forth and TILs - my re-implementation of VT Lisp was influenced by TILs (and later extended by a grad student with a prolog compiler (WAM implementation) that was also TIL influenced).

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
"A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H".Split(new char[] { '+' }).Select(x => "+" + x);
```

Comment: Note this would add a '+' before the first character as well. Not sure what the use case is so it's hard to know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: That works, but what if it were multiple chars e.g. `"A+B-C+D+E-F+G-H".Split(new char[] { '+', '-' })`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There may be a better way of accomplishing your goal. Can you give more info?

Comment: Its for calculations, I was in the middle of making a method called `IntPtr GetAddress(string addr)` which calculates the open process's address, it accepts a hex string address but it can start with `base` if you want to get the address starting from the base address, so if you were to do `IntPtr GetAddress("base+AAA+BBB-4+C-ABCCC")` it would return `new IntPtr(MainModule.BaseAddress+0xAAA+0xBBB-0x4+0xC-0xABCCC)` i need it to split the string, but keep the split chars (+ & -), so i could add those which need to be added and subtract those that need to be subtracted.

Comment: OK Yeah it's probably better to do something like NetMerge is suggesting