# C# Split text by multicharacter delimiter and keep the delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, split

I've got the below:

Line A

1. Snowflake cake flour 12.5kg R142.99
2. Libresse Toilet Rolls 24s R82.99 3. Snowflake Self Raising Flour 10 x 1kg R264.99 20 x 500g R264.99
3. Elite Rice 10kg R85.99 5. Allsome Rice 10kg 133.99 5kg 88.99
4. Nola Mayonnaise 6 x 750g
5. Aromat
6. 

I need it to look like this:

1. Snowflake cake flour 12.5kg R142.99
2. Libresse Toilet Rolls 24s R82.99
3. Snowflake Self Raising Flour 10 x 1kg R264.99
   20 x 500g R264.99
4. Elite Rice 10kg R85.99
5. Allsome Rice 10kg R133.99
   5kg R88.99
6. Nola Mayonnaise 6 x 750g
7. Aromat
8. 

As you can see though they're not very consistent. Sometimes they come with pricing that starts with an R, sometimes they don't. Sometimes they have no pricing whatsoever and sometimes they don't even have sizes. Sometimes the writing is on the same line and sometimes it's on a different line. Sometimes the products don't even have a description as the client is waiting to see what they can add in that place. Sometimes they have more than one pricing or more than one item for the same list number.

I've managed to achieve the first effect, where each item appears on a different line, but the part where the items that have multiple products assigned to them is perplexing me. I've got the text to split alright but keeping the delimiter, which is multi-character is failing.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


string text = @"Line A
Snowflake cake flour 12.5kg R142.99
2. Libresse Toilet Rolls 24s R82.99 3. Snowflake Self Raising Flour 10 x 1kg R264.99 20 x 500g R264.99
4. Elite Rice 10kg R85.99 5. Allsome Rice 10kg R133.99 5kg 88.99
6. Nola Mayonnaise 6 x 750g
7. Aromat
8.";

List<string> listItems = new List<string>();
int itemNumber = 1; // Counter for item numbers

foreach (string line in text.Split(Environment.NewLine))
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || line.StartsWith("Line A"))
    {
        continue; // Skip empty lines and Line A
    }

    var subItems = Regex.Split(line, @"\d+\.\s+"); // Split by number-point-space
    foreach (string subItem in subItems)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subItem))
        {
            listItems.Add($"{itemNumber++}. {subItem}"); // Prepend number and space
        }
    }
}

// Handle nested items with point-number-number-space format
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Count; i++)
{ 
    var parts = Regex.Split(listItems[i], @"\.\d+\d+\s+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (parts.Length > 1)
    {
        listItems[i] = parts[0]; // Keep original item unchanged
        listItems.Insert(i + 1, parts[1]) ; // Add nested item after
    }
}

// Print each item
foreach (string item in listItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

[image: This] is the current output:

I've tried `string pattern = @"\.\d+\d+\s+";` but that just appends the pattern to the end of the string instead of ".99 "

The reason why it's not similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141109/can-you-split-a-string-and-keep-the-split-chars) is because that has single characters that they use for delimiting. Mine uses multiple characters. The method that I tried from that question is not working.[image: Image 2]

Notice that my output is completely blank. It's not loading in the least when using the code in that question.

Comment: Don't fix broken input. Make the source fix it.

Comment: `PATTERN` must be turned into `(?=PATTERN)` to keep the delimiter inside the split chunks.

Comment: This doesn't work as it doesn't split by pattern in this regard

Comment: It does split keeping it in the result. If you need to have the match as a separate entry in the results, just capture it: `PATTERN` > `(PATTERN)`